# angularjs filter 'date' and $locale service

Tags: angularjs, filter, localization, internationalization

it seems that angularjs embed some internationalized resources:

> Angular supports i18n/l10n for date, number and currency filters.
>   Additionally, Angular supports localizable pluralization support
>   through the ngPluralize directive. All localizable Angular components
>   depend on locale-specific rule sets managed by the $locale service.

If found the [`$locale` service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$locale) but don't kwnow how to specify the locale in fr-fr...

The following code :

```
{{article.date_collected | date:'EEEE dd MMMM yyyy'}}
```

Gives :

> Monday 06 October 2014

But I want :

> Lundi 06 Octobre 2014

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Finally I found the response on the angular github page: 
https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-i18n#bower-angular-i18n

EDIT : more info for what worked for me

In your root app directory, install resources from bower

```
bower install angular-i18n
```

Add a `<script>` to your index.html between this comments tags if you use bower/buildjs to compact all your scripts to `vendor.js` file :

```
<!-- endbower -->
<script src="bower_components/angular-i18n/angular-locale_fr-fr.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->
```

That's it.

Comment: Could you add an example to the answer?

Comment: Example would be good. I could not find anything helpful behind that link.

Comment: still no example ? it would really help !

Comment: Hi, this _issue_ appends because of `bower` and `grunt-wiredep` plugin, as it's not possible for me to create a `jsfiddle`, `plunkr` or any other js sandbox because they don't allow use of `Grunt` tools. I can suggest you to read the `grunt-wiredep` [documentation](http://stephenplusplus.github.io/grunt-wiredep/) and `bower` [documentation](https://bower.io/). BTW, this post is old, 2014! I'm sure angular has better way to do it for now ;)

Comment: can we change it according to user-selection? i have language drop-down with 3 different language so i need it render dynamically according to different language.

Answer (score 10):

Example of use, as per
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/i18n

1) get the locale you need from the angular repo or through bower, e.g.
//raw.githubusercontent.com/angular/bower-angular-i18n/master/angular-locale_fr-fr.js

2) include it after the angular library, e.g.

```
<script src="vendor/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="vendor/angular-locale_fr-fr.js"></script>
```

3) now whenever you display a date using the ng date filter, it will be in French-France, not US English format, e.g.

```
{{date | date: 'fullDate'}}
```

There's also gotta be a way to handle several locals programmatically, it's done on the AngularJS home page "beer counter" example, with

```
angular.module('app-us', ['app', 'ngLocal.us']);
angular.module('app-sk', ['app', 'ngLocal.sk']);
```

and

```
<script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.4.4/i18n/angular-locale_sk.js"></script>
<script>
angular.module('ngLocal.sk', [])._configBlocks.push(angular.module('ngLocale')._configBlocks[0]);
</script>
<script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.4.4/i18n/angular-locale_en-us.js"></script>
<script>
angular.module('ngLocal.us', [])._configBlocks.push(angular.module('ngLocale')._configBlocks[0]);
angular.bootstrap(document, ['ngRoute', 'homepage', 'ngLocal.us']);
</script>
```

And here's a cleaner way to do it:
https://github.com/lgalfaso/angular-dynamic-locale

Comment: Thanks @pansay for your answer. But be careful folks, in my case, the issue was caused by `grunt` / `bower` auto include libraries between html comments tags `<!-- endbower -->`, `<!-- endbuild -->`, ...