# Angularjs i18n disable locale on date

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi fellow programmers,

I am using i18n localization provided by angular js, it can be found [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/i18n).

Currently, I am using date filter to convert a date to 'day' like this in my html view:

> {{ note.NoteDateTime | date:"EEEE" }}

This converts the date to day, and but output is converted to another locale. (I am using Netherlands).

I need to disable this translation here and output as 'Default English'.

Thank you,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [angularjs filter 'date' and $locale service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26216414/angularjs-filter-date-and-locale-service)

Comment: @KannanThangadurai The link you have mentioned demonstrates how we can use $locale service of angular to convert date to corresponding locale, my question is to disable the locale specifically.