# how to format ui-grid date columns for different regions

Tags: angular-ui-grid, date-formatting, ui-grid

Applying a date format to a grid is easily done {  type: 'date',  cellFilter: "date:\'MM/dd/yyyy\'" } 
however what if we want to display a different format for French - Canadian date:\'yyyy-MM-dd\'

I have a grid which uses 'i18nService' to translate the grid like this
   app.controller('ctrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$timeout', '$filter','i18nService', 'uiGridConstants', function ($scope, $http, $timeout, $filter, $i18nService, uiGridConstants) {
  $i18nService.setCurrentLang('fr');
           ...

now how do I format the dates in the grid differently based on language the grid is rendered in?

Comment: This sounds like a more generic i18n question. Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/32111231/4614870